# How could actor know if it has all the responses it needs in order to proceed?

Tags: scala, akka

I am fairly new to akka and not sure about approaching this problem.

- I have a `Monitor` actor that spawns 2 other actors as `DiskMonitor` and `MemoryMonitor`
- `DiskMonitor` checks the diskUsage and report `DiskReport` message
- `MemoryMonitor` checks the diskUsage and report `MemoryReport` message

I want to combine the `DiskReport` and `MemoryReport` into `Report` Object and send to to remote machine via an API.

**Questions**

Since `DiskMonitor` and `MemoryMonitor` both are actors they send the response back to caller once they are done with their work

**Monitor**

```
diskMonitor ! DiskMonitorRequest
memoryMonitor ! MemoryMonitorRequest
```

How would `Monitor` know that it has all the results that it needs so that it can create `Report` object and send it via API?

Are actors good way to approach this problem?

I also read about future but I don't understand them well and not sure if they would be helpful in this problem context

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way of doing these things. Other options can be through using `context.become` or the trait `FSM`.

```
class Monitor extends Actor {
  // Somewhere do this:    
  diskMonitor ! DiskMonitorRequest
  memoryMonitor ! MemoryMonitorRequest

  var diskMonitorResult = Option.empty[DiskMonitor]
  var memoryMonitorResult = Option.empty[MemoryMonitor]

  def recieve = {
    case d: DiskMonitor => 
      diskMonitorResult = Some(d)
      checkIfCompleted()
    case m: MemoryMonitor =>
      memoryMonitorResult = Some(m)
      checkIfCompleted()
  }

  def checkIfCompleted = {
    (diskMonitorResult, memoryMonitorResult) match {
      case (Some(diskMonitor), Some(memoryMonitor)) =>
         // send to external API
         externalApi ! Report(diskMonitor, memoryMonitor)
         // Possibly stop this actor
      case _ => // do nothing
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ask pattern` and combine futures..

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

class Monitor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = context.dispatcher

  val diskM: ActorRef = context.system.actorOf(Props[DiskMonitor])
  val memoryM: ActorRef = context.system.actorOf(Props[MemoryMonitor])
  val remoteM: ActorRef = context.system.actorOf(Props[RemoteMachine])

  override def preStart: Unit = {
    log.info("Monitor Created..")
    self ! GenerateReport
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case GenerateReport =>
      (diskM ? MakeDiskReport).mapTo[DiskReport].zip((memoryM ? MakeMemoryReport)
        .foreach { case (diskR, memR) =>
          remoteM ! Report(memR.report, diskR.report)
        }
  }
}

class DiskMonitor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case MakeDiskReport =>
      log.info("Creating DiskReport..")
      val client = sender
      client ! DiskReport("DiskReport")
  }
}

class MemoryMonitor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case MakeMemoryReport =>
      log.info("Creating MemoryReport..")
      val client = sender
      client ! MemoryReport("MemoryReport")
  }
}

class RemoteMachine extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Report(memr, diskr) =>
      log.info(s"Final Report.. $memr, $diskr")
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val sys = ActorSystem()
  sys.actorOf(Props[Monitor])
}

sealed trait Message

case object GenerateReport extends Message

case object MakeDiskReport extends Message

case object MakeMemoryReport extends Message

case class DiskReport(report: String) extends Message

case class MemoryReport(report: String) extends Message

case class Report(memReport: String, diskReport: String) extends Message
```